# Binding List View and show the clicked item on the same page, but item value not showing

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, data-binding

I got a problem with list view binding item source in Xamarin Forms

I have  a list view on screen one and item view on screen two. I am doing item source binding for
list view. Once an item has been clicked, if it is landscape mode I will attach item view to the
Frame not jumping to the second screen, but if it is portrait mode app will direct users to the screen
two-item view.

```
<ListView
    x:Name="Items_ListView"

    ItemTapped="ListView_ItemTapped"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Items_List}">
```

As showing below is the item view screen and I am doing text binding as well. However, the problem is the tile value is not showing when I attach this view to Frame. While if I do list view item source = list instead of binding context, the code will work fine.

```
    <Entry
    x:Name="Title"
    BackgroundColor="White"
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    Text="{Binding Item_Title, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Does anyone have any idea about this ? Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean by "While if I do list view item source = list instead of binding context" Can you write it in code syntax not in literature?

Comment: Can you supply your definition of `Item_Title`?

Comment: Hi Cfun, it means in C# I do listview.itemsource = itemlist instead of ItemsSource="{Binding Items_List}" in xmal file

Comment: Hi @Bijington    public string Item_Title
        {
            get { return Item.Title; }
            set { Item.Title = value; OnPropertyChanged("Item_Title"); }
        }

Comment: @Cfun it means in C# I do listview.itemsource = itemlist instead of ItemsSource="{Binding Items_List}" in xmal file –

Comment: @yihan thanks. It sounds like you are having a few binding problems. One quick point, your property is called `Event_Title` not `Item_Title`. Are you setting the `BindingContext` on your main view which contains the list view. If not you made want to start there https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/basic-bindings#bindings-with-a-binding-context

Comment: @Bijington sorry my type mistake, it is Item_Title, and I am binding list view item source on screen one and binding title text on screen two

Comment: Are you using MVVM (you need to set something like `BindingContext = new ScreenTwoViewModel`) or just placing your properties inside the code behind (e.g. ScreenTwoView.xaml.cs) (set something like `BindingContext = this`). Obviously replacing the class names with your actual names

Comment: @Bijington Yes, I am using MVVM. I have two screens, but for landscape mode I will attach the second screen view to the screen one as well which means on left hand side showing list view and right hand side showing item detail. For both screens i have ViewModels separately

Comment: "when I attach this view to Frame" - where is the code that does this?

Comment: @Jason FormsView formpage = new FormsView(item);              
             Sub_Right_Frame.Content = formpage.GetFormView(item);

Comment: please include all of the relevant code IN your post.  Code stuffed in comments is unreadable.  It seems likely the problem is somewhere in FormsView

Comment: @Jason Hi Jason, thanks for your comments. This is very specific problem and I think the problem is about the way I assign list view data source or the way I assign item detail on the screen one. Because if I change it to listview.itemsource = itemlist instead of ItemsSource="{Binding Items_List}" the item detail will show up

Comment: @Jason  I think I get a clue because I have two ViewModels and bindingcontexts on one screen

Comment: @yihan If you used `ItemsSource="{Binding Items_List}`, you also need to binding BindingContext to ViewModel in xaml or code behind. Please take a look: [Data Bindings to MVVM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm)